# Overwrite Expansion File (Android)

Tags: android, expansion, apk-expansion-files

My expansion file is 200 Mb. I can't see it viable to pull files out of it in realtime (too slow for my purposes). So, I'm extracting all of them to regular files in other folder.

Now, I want to save some space on the card for my beloved user by avoiding app data duplication.

I have an idea to delete the actual expansion file and replace it with a zero size dummy, to fool Google Play and prevent it from downloading 200Mb again. Would that trick work?

I can't test for that as my app is not published yet.

Comment: what format is your expansion file in? as far as I know, an android .obb is usually a mountable disk image, which means mounting and reading a file directly is at least as fast as reading the extracted file

Comment: Some of the .obb formats are compressed, and so probably would involve overhead to access, just as any other compressed filesystem would.  However, it may not be an unacceptable amount of overhead.

Comment: It's in zip format. Trust me, it is very slow to open (ef=APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(con,mVer,pVer)), and probably eats a lot of RAM when kept open.

Comment: As far as I know, Google Play will *not* redownload the expansion file unless the expansion file actually changes. According to [the expansion file guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html), you should not move, rename, or delete the .obb, as that will cause it to be redownloaded. I would assume this extends to replacing the .obb as well.

Comment: To test the apk expansion file download you have to make your app as draft app in your developer account.
I don't think what you are thinking will work because if you have seen example given in library there you have to mention file size(XAPKFile) and at each launch library will verify the size of available file.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what kind of data they look at in order to redownload the expansion file, but if you don't want to use it as intended I think you'll have an easier time hosting your files and downloading them through your own download mechanism.

Comment: Not accepted. You have to pay for a high traffic hosting then.

Comment: After thinking about I've commed to the conclusion that you can't handle this. Play uses the users apk version and compares it with the newest and based on that download the current expansion files. This is the only way it would make sense to implement it. Feel free to test my hyphothesis.